# Generate Hash Key of (void *) data

Tags: c++, hashtable, hash, ns-3

I want to know that how to Generate a hash key of void data.

I am working a project of networking and dealing with packets. I have to generate the hash table. on which packet header to be hashed. But i don't know the structure Or class of packet header. So, any idea about this. i just thinking of converting it to void. and hash the void data to generate the hash key.

ANY OTHER IDEA. GOOD Logic will be welcomed.

Comment: Basically this isn't going to work. Thinking about this from a Java perspective, hashCode must be consistant with equals. If you know nothing about the data, how can you ever know if two are equal - except by comparing every byte? And if you don't know if they are equal, how can you expect to find them in a hashtable?

Comment: Thanks... OK that is absolutely right. But i am thinking in differently. Suppose there is a void type data. and we have to save this in a table.

Comment: There is no difficulty in hashing and comparing blobs of data if (a) you know how long they are and (b) you are willing to accept length equality plus byte-wise equality as your definition of equality of the two blobs. The problem is fairly easy, but you haven't really said *where you are stuck*, so it is going to be hard for people to provide good answers.

Comment: Additional comment: *"how to Generate a hash key of void data"* is badly phrased. There is no "void data", a `void*` is a pointer to data of *unspecified* type, but you can not instantiate a variable of type `void`. Instead you'll treat the thing on the other end of the point-to-void as an array of bytes (typically represented by `char` or `unsigned char` (or on machines where a byte is an octet `int8_t` or `uint8_t`)).

Comment: Do you at least know the size of the data? If not you can't properly work with it since you'll risk accessing invalid memory.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [CityHash](http://code.google.com/p/cityhash/source/browse/trunk/README), which has a function that I think is suitable for your input:

```
// Hash function for a byte array.
uint64 CityHash64(const char *buf, size_t len);
```

As far as I can tell, char being used as the input type is just for convenience--it does not imply for example that the function will stop hashing if it finds a zero byte.

There's also a 128-bit version, and other things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any hash function that accepts any type of pointer as long as it also takes in a length for the buffer. Just cast the pointer and use it. Most hash functions will use a `char *` input and a `size_t` length.

From your question though, you might not have the length of the header. It won't work if you don't have this length.

Comment: Thanks... The length issue is nothing and i have. and afcouse there are many functions. But my i want to do this. :). One blooper, i am doing is char *a = &(char)(void)(ccHrd); This is i know wrong but. it tells the sense that what i am trying to do.